# Conversion From nvarchar value to to data type int failed?

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server, datatable

I have this Table Type

```
CREATE TYPE ItemTableType AS TABLE   
( 
  BrandId INT, 
  BranchId INT,
  InventoryCategoryId INT,
  Attributes nvarchar(Max),
  Price Decimal(18,2),
  [Description] nvarchar(Max)
);
```

I create a datatable in my C# code like this

```
 var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("BrandId");
            dt.Columns.Add("BranchId");
            dt.Columns.Add("attributes");
            dt.Columns.Add("InventoryCategoryId");
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");
            dt.Columns.Add("Description");

            foreach (var item in inventoryItems)
            {
                DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
                r["BrandId"] = item.BrandId;
                r["BranchId"] = item.BranchId;
                r["InventoryCategoryId"] = item.InventoryCategoryId;
                r["attributes"] = item.Attributes;
                r["Price"] = item.Price;
                r["Description"] = item.Description;
                dt.Rows.Add(r);

            }
```

[image]

when I try to pass my dt into my SP I get

```
{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '{"PartNumber":"XA1167","Qty":999,"CleanedPartNumber":"1167"}' to data type int.


The data for table-valued parameter "@Source" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 245, state: 1
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at line 202
ClientConnectionId:7a91a363-e5a0-4476-a92f-d02c30262728
Error Number:245,State:1,Class:16}
```

why is it thinking it is an Int when?

Comment: I will take a wild guess that the order of columns in your data row does not match the order of columns in your data table.  Attributes and CategoryId are reversed. If that's not it, then maybe the values inserted into "item" object are inserted incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that the third column in the type you created `InventoryCategory` is `Int` while the datatable third column is `varchar`. You must reorder the columns in the datatable.

While adding columns use:

```
dt.Columns.Add("InventoryCategoryId");
dt.Columns.Add("attributes");
```

Comment: did not know that it had to be in the exact same order thought they would match up with the name but I guess if I think of the table type as paramaters I see why order matters.